# What is the best way of storing a CSV or TSV file data?

Tags: android

I have a CSV file with large amount of data. I have to read this file and randomly selected data for displaying in my android app. Right now I have store the the CSV file in res/raw folder and every time the app starts I create a static ListArray store the entire contents of CSV file after parsing into a the ListArray and then every time I use this list for getting data.

While this strategy works so far the problem is that some times the list items are updated but when the app restarts again those changes are not stored anywhere.

My question is that what is the best way to read contents of the CSV file and store them permanently in the app? Should I read the contents of the CSV file line by line and store the data in a sqlite database.

Please any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Refer to this link. You will find a way to store it in sqlite https://parallelcodes.com/android-csv-file-import-to-sqlite-database/

Comment: @HappySingh Thank you very much for the link. It is very helpful.

Comment: I am adding this to an Answer. Please accept so in future folks can have this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can refer to this blog tutorial. It has some brief explanation of what you want.

**Stroing .CSV  in SQLite Android**

https://parallelcodes.com/android-csv-file-import-to-sqlite-database/

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a SQLite db and index columns appropriately.  Preferably include the .db file with your app, rather than the csv directly (although you cna parse it at runtime on first installation, why do that when you can just include the translated file?).

Comment: Can you please tell what is the translated file?